# JavaFX program is hanging up with no errors and isn't changing background color

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I am fairly new to JavaFX and our instructor gave us an assignment far more complicated than what we were taught. I have built all of the interface and logic but my program is hanging up and I can't figure out why, it makes it past the sleep stage. Can anyone help?
Update: I found out the while loop is infinitely running and freezing the program. Is there a way to make it halt the program with an event listener?

```
package assign3;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.CornerRadii;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Question2 extends Application
{
    private boolean runGame = true;
    private int level = 1;
    public static final int RED = 1;
    public static final int GREEN = 2;
    public static final int BLUE = 3;
    public static final int ORANGE = 4;
    private static BorderPane obBorder = new BorderPane();
    private static HBox obPane = new HBox();
    private static HBox obStart = new HBox();
    private static Button btRed = new Button("Red");
    private static Button btGreen = new Button("Green");
    private static Button btBlue = new Button("Blue");
    private static Button btOrange = new Button("Orange");
    private static Button btStart = new Button("Start");

    @Override
    public void start( Stage obPrimeStage ) throws Exception
    {        
        obStart.getChildren().add(btStart);
        obPane.getChildren().addAll(btRed, btGreen, btBlue, btOrange);

        obBorder.setCenter(obPane);
        obBorder.setBottom(obStart);
        obPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        obStart.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Scene obScene = new Scene(obBorder, 400, 400);

        obPrimeStage.setTitle("Question 2");
        obPrimeStage.setScene(obScene);
        obPrimeStage.show();

        btStart.setOnAction((ActionEvent start) -> {
            try {
                runGame();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });       
    }


    private void runGame() throws InterruptedException
    {
        int randomColour;

        do{
            ArrayList<Integer> colours = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<Integer> guesses = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i = 0; i <= level; i++)
            {
                //randomColour = (int)((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
                randomColour = 1;

                if(randomColour == RED)
                {
                    obBorder.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.RED, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                    System.out.println("Wake up plz");
                    obBorder.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.TRANSPARENT, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
                    colours.add(RED);
                }
                else if(randomColour == BLUE)
                {
                    obBorder.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.BLUE, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                    obBorder.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.TRANSPARENT, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
                    colours.add(BLUE);
                }
                else if(randomColour == GREEN)
                {
                    obBorder.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.GREEN, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                    obBorder.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.TRANSPARENT, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
                    colours.add(GREEN);
                }
                else if(randomColour == ORANGE)
                {
                    obBorder.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.ORANGE, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                    obBorder.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.TRANSPARENT, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
                    colours.add(GREEN);
                }

                while(guesses.size() < colours.size())
                {
                    btRed.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> 
                    {
                        obBorder.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.RED, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
                        guesses.add(RED);
                    });

                    btGreen.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> 
                    {
                        obBorder.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.GREEN, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
                        guesses.add(GREEN);
                    });

                    btBlue.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> 
                    {
                        obBorder.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.BLUE, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
                        guesses.add(BLUE);
                    });

                    btOrange.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> 
                    {
                        obBorder.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.ORANGE, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
                        guesses.add(ORANGE);
                    });
                }

                for(int j = 0; j < colours.size(); j++)
                {
                    if(guesses.get(j) != colours.get(j))
                    {
                        runGame = false;
                    }
                    if(runGame)
                    {
                        level += 1;
                    }
                }
            }

        }while(runGame);
    }  

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Application.launch(args);

    }
}
```

Comment: Never put an event handler inside a loop except when creating nodes dynamically and you want to add event handling to the nodes. There may be other exceptions. Also, it seems you have a while(true) loop running in your program's main thread. That is going to cause the program to freeze.  You need to learn about JavaFx Animation class and the game loop. This is a great tutorial: https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-javafx-for-game-development--cms-23835

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a read.

Answer (score 0):

Given Sedrick's comment and questioning my instructor I realize that this is all better handled by only running my program through event handlers. Loops inside of JavaFX iterations do not work properly and they should not be implemented.

I must run my first iteration on a btStart ActionEvent and the rest through user click events on other buttons.